# Call page load event after every 10 seconds

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm having a scenario to call load event after every 5 seconds or 10 seconds someone help me, with some related links.

Comment: add a meta tag to your form ?

Comment: Do you really just want to call the event handler, or do you want to reload the page? A bit more effort on the question will get you better answers (or, at this point, any answers at all). :-)

Answer (score 3):

The page load event is fired once, when the page loads. If you want to run a function every 10 seconds, use:

```
window.setInterval(function, 10000)
```

See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) documentation

Comment: for "every 10 seconds", shouldn't that be `setInterval`, not `setTimeout` ?

Comment: And 10 is 10ms, not 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend instead to use an UpdatePanel with a Timer for your issue, you can read more about this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx